# For the size doesn't always matters

Tags: riddle

Darkness makes it harder to work with me.

For it blinds your eyes but doesn't effects mine.

Simple but important is my unpaid job,

For I become the slave once and for all

I work all the way till I die,

until my main part is no more subtle.

That's how my life sequence is joined.

Tell me what am I ?

Comment: A few of these answers seem highly plausible, when you're commenting on someone's incorrect answer it helps to provide feedback. For example, could you give some feedback as to why @Mikas answer is not correct? Other then, of course, it not being the answer you had in mind.If the answer is, no, that you cannot, then I would consider amending your description.

Comment: @Colton .. check out answer which i accepted.. if i would have given the description as to why mikas answer is wrong .. it would have made the answer too obvious..

Comment: @Colton : Moreover the word "subtle" has a hidden meaning. If I gave all the things directly than, how would it be a riddle? We twist things in a riddle and that's what I did. And the one who got its meaning right got the right answer. :)

Comment: I disagree wholly on your first point. I was not suggesting that your description was inqdeuqate, or that the clues you gave were too subtle. I was merely pointing out that it IS possible to give constructive feedback on these in a way that shows the user their answer is not applicable given your current description. This doesn't imply that you have to provide additional information, but rather that you should be able to easily distinguish a bad answer from a good one for one reason or another. There are 3 or 4 answers for this that work just as well as your accepted one, my friend.

Comment: @Colton Agreed, although I would think he would have to give more description if the answers are very close, I think the button answer is much more apt, given the fact they also have eyes and the last five lines essentially amount to being useful for one purpose and talk about irrevocable "joining." Why should one word be picked out so heftily?

Comment: @theREALyumdub : the button answer would have been correct if i haven't used the word "SUBTLE" which is a synonym of sharp. It was used intentionally and it was the job of the people to interpret it in the way it was intended to be. Moreover I gave proper explanation as of why the answers other than needles are not correct.

Comment: @Maniraj Your reasoning with "subtle" here is not correct, as "subtle" is not a synonym for sharp in your context.  Subtle can, in fact, be defined as "clever", which is a synonym for "sharp", but in this context you wanted it to be used as the definition of sharp that describes something with an edge used to cut. If you wanted people to correlate the two distinct definitions of sharp, I would have added the lateral thinking tag.

Comment: Your title has incorrect grammar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are:

> a needle (sewing not knitting)

Darkness makes it harder to work with me

> It's hard to sew in the dark

For it blinds your eyes but doesn't effects mine.

> The eye of the person sewing cant see in the dark, to sew. But the eye of their needle isn't affected by whether it's light or dark.

Simple but important is my unpaid job,

> Sewing/stitching is simple but so very important - without it no clothes, many functional and ornamental objects, safety equipment, etc.

For I become the slave once and for all

> The needle is a tool that serves people/society

I work all the way till I die,

> All it does is work

until my main part is no more subtle

> Subtle can mean sharp - when the needle becomes blunt (or equally when the sharp tip breaks off), is when you throw it away.

That's how my life sequence is joined.

> That is its life. Also "joining" is what a needle does when it sews.

Comment: winner winner , chicken dinner :) Correct answer :D

Comment: I figured after a bunch of possible ideas, that it might be a tool of some kind ("work with me", also fits with line 3 and maybe with lines 1/2/5), and that gave a context to "mine" (line 2) and sensible clear meaning to line 6. Tools for which line 2 makes sense = not that many. Line 6 confirmed the answer by fitting closely.

Answer (score 5):

Is the answer:

> light (possibly specifically candlelight)

For the size doesn't always matters

> light doesn't have to a size per se

Darkness makes it harder to work with me.

> this one is obvious

For it blinds your eyes but doesn't effects mine.

> darkness doesn't stop light.

Simple but important is my unpaid job,

> again, obvious - it lights stuff up

For I become the slave once and for all

> People carry light around and use it at will

I work all the way till I die,

> It works until it dies out

until my main part is no more subtle.

> as above, until the light or candle burns out

That's how my life sequence is joined.

> That's how a candle is burned up

Tell me what am I ?

Comment: to make the hidden block, use >! before a line

Comment: No problem, in the future though, you can check out the help page before you post, https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help.

Comment: Candle is not the main part for light .. moreover the word subtle had a hidden meaning. A good attempt .. but not the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

You are a

> Button

Darkness makes it harder to work with me.

> Buttoning up a shirt in the dark is a real pain

For it blinds your eyes but doesn't effects mine.

> The eyes of a button are not for sight

For I become the slave once and for all

> A button is tethered to a shirt for the lifetime of the garment

I work all the way till I die,

> A button is only useful for as long as it's tethered

until my main part is no more subtle.

> A button coming undon

That's how my life sequence is joined.

> When it falls off, it no longer has purpose.

Comment: A very good answer all the way.. but not the correct one as the word "subtle" has more significance in this riddle.Although you were very close to the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly:

> Road reflectors (cat eyes)

Darkness makes it harder to work with me.

> Mainly used to show the road on darkness, and if it doesn't work, it is harder to drive

For it blinds your eyes but doesn't effects mine.

> A little distraction, but its 'eye' is not affected

Simple but effective is my unpaid job,

> it is simple and effective

For I become the slave once and for all

> Once installed, usually remains forever

I work all the way till I die,

> if has a battery (e.g. solar), it can gradually die

until my main part is no more subtle.
That's how my life sequence is joined.

> Not sure

Comment: No.. not the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you a

> [Star-nosed mole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-nosed_mole)?

Darkness makes it harder to work with me.

> Star-nosed moles dig tunnels underground

For it blinds your eyes but doesn't effects mine.

> Star-nosed moles are already blind, and they use their noses to find things

For I become the slave once and for all

> A common trope of slavery is mining tunnels, which is essentially what they do.

I work all the way till I die,

> Star-nosed moles will dig their entire lives until they die.

until my main part is no more subtle.

> Gardeners will often notice a series of tunnels in their gardens, which is the life work of our little friends.

That's how my life sequence is joined.

> Perhaps referencing conjoining tunnels together in a network?

Comment: Good thought but your description a few lines one of them being "until my main part is no more subtle" doesn't fits at all ..

Comment: I figured it was worth a shot, but you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the answer is

> the Sun

Darkness makes it harder to work with me :

> sun is often the opposite of darkness

For it blinds your eyes but doesn't effects mine :

> you can't look at the Sun

Simple but effective is my unpaid job :

> produce energy and doesn't touch money of it

For I become the slave once and for all
I work all the way till I die,
until my main part is no more subtle.
That's how my life sequence is joined

> The Sun will "burn" until it runs out of energy/mass

Comment: On the wrong track..

Comment: Moreover welcome to Puzzling.SE!, whenever you answer a question try putting it in spoiler tag, so that others can attempt the riddle without seeing the answer. Try reading the entire [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) page to get your first badge.

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> Writing Utensil

Darkness makes it harder to work with me.
For it blinds your eyes but doesn't effects mine.

> It's hard to write at night because you can't see what you are writing however it can still write perfectly fine

Simple but important is my unpaid job,

> It's important for the human civilization to be able to write.

For I become the slave once and for all

> Not sure about this one but maybe something about being used by the same person only for writing or drawing(?)

I work all the way till I die,

> You use it until it loses it's ink (or graphite)

until my main part is no more subtle.

> Until it can't write properly

That's how my life sequence is joined.

> That's the life sequence of a writing utensil

Comment: Good attempt.. but not the right answer.

Comment: The word "subtle" has a hidden meaning. If I gave all the things directly than, how would it be a riddle?

Comment: i interpreted as the pens get older and such it starts to fail to write properly not getting ink out and having to the the heat strategies

Comment: Good thought but not the correct one

Answer (score 1):

What about :

> a yawning

Darkness makes it harder to work with me

> when comes the night people start to yawn

For it blinds your eyes but doesn't effects mine.

> yawning makes blind your eyes

Simple but important is my unpaid job,

> simple thing and important but we don't pay much attention to it

For I become the slave once and for all

> when you start yawning you won't stop

I work all the way till I die,

> the only way to stop is sleeping

until my main part is no more subtle

> when you don't stop yawning it's no more subtle

That's how my life sequence is joined.

> It's over until the next sequence

Comment: No way .. :D how can yawning blind your eyes.. one can yawn with open eyes.

Answer (score 1):

How about

> A vehicle

Darkness makes it harder to work with me.

> Harder to drive at night

For it blinds your eyes but doesn't effects mine.

> Headlights still work at night. Still, they do not illuminate the area fully. Also, you can get blinded by headlights of other drivers.

For I become the slave once and for all

> You could say the vehicle is the driver's slave

I work all the way till I die,

> ...like any piece of machinery

until my main part is no more subtle.

> A dying engine makes loud sounds

That's how my life sequence is joined.

> Not sure, maybe a vehicle will go to a metal scrapyard, where parts might be salvaged/recycled and used in new vehicles.

Comment: Good attempt but not the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer

> A potato?

Darkness makes it harder to work with me.

> A potato has eyes but do not see

For it blinds your eyes but doesn't effects mine.

> A potato has eyes but do not see

Simple but important is my unpaid job,

> A potato is food

For I become the slave once and for all

> It is food for my body

I work all the way till I die,

> A potato grows

until my main part is no more subtle.

> A potato plant grows green then gets brown when "ripe"

That's how my life sequence is joined.

> A potato grows from a potato

Tell me what am I ?

> A potato

Comment: A wrong approach as well as a wrong answer.

Comment: Moreover, "Darkness makes it harder to work with me" the starting part remained unexplained.

Answer (score 1):

This is not so much an answer, but I want to generalize Colton's point in this way: I can understand there might be hidden clues and meaning twitching in a riddle. However, a riddle should be strict enough to not allow ALMOST ANYTHING to be an answer. Here I present the answer

> "Any tool or thing that can be used as a tool, thus any thing (non-living)"

Darkness makes it harder to work with me.

> It is harder to work with any thing during the night, 'cause you can't see.

For it blinds your eyes but doesn't effects mine.

> See previous point

For I become the slave once and for all

> When you use a thing, you could refer to it as a slave

until my main part is no more subtle.

> It is easy to define a "main" part for each thing, and it is in most times philosophically valid to describe it as "subtle" when it's working, and not when it's not, since when it's not useable anymore it will exhibit defects.

That's how my life sequence is joined.

> Considering "sequence" is "a series of events", it could be widely synonymous to time, and the "joined" part just means "time goes on"

Thus, I think this riddle should REALLY need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer

> To do with sewing or stitching?

Darkness makes it harder to work with me.

> Sewing in the dark is very difficult!

For it blinds your eyes but doesn't effects mine.

> Possibly a reference to the eye of a needle

Simple but important is my unpaid job,

> Holding cloth together is very simple, but very important

For I become the slave once and for all

> A stitch once in place will always hold material together...

I work all the way till I die,

> ...until it breaks

until my main part is no more subtle.That's how my life sequence is joined.

> Not sure on this but possibly referring to a row of stitches holding together

Tell me what am I ?